# Why don't changes made to content blocks in dynamic content update automatically?

Tags: ampscript, dynamic, content-builder, dynamic-content

I have an email with a dynamic content block that has 10 rules and 10 associated content blocks. When I make a change to any of the associated content blocks the content doesn't update in the dynamic content block automatically. I have to physically go into the dyanmic content block, open the rule and resave.

Is this the only way to do this? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

We have gotten around this issue by using Ampscript IF statements and code snippets, for example:

> > %%[ IF ( @*VAR1* == '*Value1*' OR @*VAR1* == '*Value2*' OR @*VAR1* == '*Value3*')THEN]%% %%=ContentBlockbyID("40312")=%% %%[ELSE]%% %%=ContentBlockbyID("40321")=%% %%[ENDIF]%%

when you do this the content is retrieved at the time of the send so the content will always be current. Let me know if this makes sense.

Marsha